# How can I make a constraint that a date is a date in Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

For the given class:

```
class User {
  Date birthday 
}
```

How can I make a constraint that ensures that birthday is a date when a user enters this in a form?

Comment: Post the code you are currently using to save the User to get the exact code to use

Answer (score 1):

If you use data binding, it will be set to null if it is not a date. If you don't, do the following to ensure it is a date:

`user.birthday = params.date("dateField")`

Comment: Do you see any exception when you try saving `1L` against a date when you do just `save()`?

Comment: Well the data would be coming from the user as a string in all cases, but you can't assign 1L to a date. You get an exception.

Comment: I don't get any exception when I just do this: `new Person(birthdate: 1L).save(flush: true)` where `birthdate` is a Date in `Person` domain.

Comment: I verified validator does not kick off if there is any datatype mismatch in domain class property.

Comment: When would data coming from a user ever be like that though? Like I said, it all comes over as strings. Also I said you can't assign 1L to a date. I can't verify the functionality of the default domain class constructor. I believe the type mismatch only comes into play when using data binding. I suppose Grails assumes you know not to deliberately assign an invalid data type. What was the value of birthdate in the saved object? null?